# Custom UIView subclass with UIScrollView, self.scrollview is (null)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Ok, so I have a custom `UIView` class called `NumberTicker`, that creates several `UIScrollViews` and populates them with `UILabels` such that a scrolling `NumberTicker` is made. However, I cannot properly access the properties of the `scrollviews`, eg.

```
[self.scrollview setHidden:YES];
// or
[self.scrollview setContentOffset:offset];
```

The above, and in fact any attempt to set or get a property of the `UIScrollView` doesn't work, except when the `scrollview` is created, before it is added as a `subview`.

Here is my `NumberTicker.h` file:

```
//  NumberTicker.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface NumberTicker : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitFour;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitFive;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitSix;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitSeven;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *digitEight;


- (id) initWithDigits:(int)digits andFrame:(CGRect)frame;
- (void) setNumberTickerTo:(int)number;

@end
```

and the NumberTicker.m:

```
//  NumberTicker.m

#import "NumberTicker.h"

@implementation NumberTicker

- (id) initWithDigits:(int)digits andFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // add digits
        [self setDigitEight:_digitEight];
        [self setDigitOne:_digitOne];
        if (digits > 6) {
            // make 8 digit ticker
            [self setFrame:frame];
            for (int i = 1; i <= digits; i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitOne withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitTwo withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitThree withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitFour withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitFive withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitSix withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitSeven withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        [self addSmallScrollView:_digitEight withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // make 6 digit ticker
            [self setFrame:frame];

            for (int i = 1; i <= digits; i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitOne withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitTwo withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitThree withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitFour withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitFive withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        [self addScrollView:_digitSix withXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*40))];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) addScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withXPos:(int)xPos
{
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, 40, 60)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(40, 660);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

// All of these properties are set properly, however I can't access them again in another method or class, after the `scrollview` has been added as a `subview`

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        // create and add labels to scrollview
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*60, 40, 60)];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:70]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        if (i == 10) {
            [label setText:@"0"];
        } else {
            [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
        }
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
    }
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (void) addSmallScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withXPos:(int)xPos
{
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, 30, 50)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(30, 550);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        // create and add labels to scrollview
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*50, 30, 50)];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:50]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        if (i == 10) {
            [label setText:@"0"];
        } else {
            [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
        }
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
    }
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (void) setNumberTickerTo:(int)number
{
    NSMutableArray *digitsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (number > 0) {
        [digitsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(number % 10)]];
        number = number / 10;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= [digitsArray count]; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                [self.digitOne setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES]; // this doesn't work
                NSLog(@"%@", self.digitOne);
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 2:
                [_digitTwo setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 3:
                [_digitThree setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 4:
                [_digitFour setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 5:
                [_digitFive setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 6:
                [_digitSix setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 7:
                [_digitSeven setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            case 8:
                [_digitEight setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[digitsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) animated:YES];
                [digitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I then call `NumberTicker` from my `ViewController.m` `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NumberTicker *numberTicker = [[NumberTicker alloc] initWithDigits:3 andFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 240, 60)];
    [self.view addSubview:numberTicker];
    [numberTicker setNumberTickerTo:345];
}
```

The `NumberTicker` view shows up on screen, as do the `scrollviews`, and everything seems fine. However, I cannot hide the `scrollviews`, use `setContentOffset` to scroll them, animate them or anything.

I have tried synthesizing the properties, setting the delegates, using IB to make a view and then connect up the outlets appropriately (I have since deleted this since I am not interested in IB for this particular class, and it did not work in any case.

If I try

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.digitOne);
```

the console shows self.digitOne as (null).

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly subclass `UIView` and programmatically create `UIScrollViews` within it, with properties that are editable in other methods later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addSmallScrollView` method is just reassigning its argument *variable* to a new scroll view, but it does nothing to the object passed as its first argument.  You aren't ever actually assigning anything to `_digitOne` for example.

I suggest that you change `addSmallScrollView` to something like `createNewSmallScrollView` and have it work more or less how it does now, but *return* the scroll view that is instantiated inside the method.  Then you can use it like:

```
_digitOne = [self createNewSmallScrollViewWithXPos:(frame.size.width - (i*30))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized your scrollview, I think you can only use the 'self.' notation if the property is synthesized.